# Patterns module : Simple YAML to XML format of the variable tag of the System Component

Tags: distributions

I am using the [Patterns](https://drupal.org/project/patterns) module to automate and make the profile maintanance easier.I have a simple problem, although it seems easy to write the XML to modify a variable tag, the only examples i can find is in the YAML parser, or the D6, not the XML i am using.So one could say that the [following YAML example](https://drupal.org/node/1468080) :

```
# YAML Variables Pattern
# QScience

info:
  title: Modify variables
  description: New test case adapted to new syntax
  author: QScience
  category: System
  version: 1.0
  core: 7.x
  author_website: http://qlectives.eu/
actions:
 - modify:
    tag: variables
    - variable
      name: user_picture_file_size
      value: 800
```

could easily ported to XML format like :

```
<pattern>
 <info>
    <title>Modify variables</title>
    <description>New test case adapted to new syntax</description>
    <author>Qscience</author>
    <category>System</category>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <core>7.x</core>
</info>
<actions>
    <modify tag="variables">
        <variable name="user_picture_file_size">800</variable>
        <!--<variable name="max_amount_limits" value="6000"/>-->?
    </modify>
</actions>
```

but this doesn't work, keep getting validation errors of **missing mandatory attributes name and value**, what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Your YAML appears to be invalid; you can validate it [here](http://xmltoyaml.com/yaml-to-xml). Currently it produces _You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping_ as an error

Comment: it is taken from the projects documentation, https://drupal.org/node/1468080, nice tool thanks, i wish i knew witch is the right syntax...

Comment: i get the same validation error for all these examples...